# Redirect with basic auth to another website (in node)

Tags: node.js, http, https, koa

How to redirect to another website with basic auth (in node)

Here is my code

```
const headers = {
  Authorization: "Basic " + 
  new Buffer(USER + ":" + PASS).toString("base64")
};

ctx.response.set(headers);
ctx.response.redirect(URL)
```

The First Response return with basic auth

```
Authorization →Basic QWRxXxXxYWRtaW4=
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →111
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Fri, 15 Dec 2017 21:49:57 GMT
Location →http://localhost:8080/edit/data/P0000013
```

The following redirected GET request doesn't contain basic auth and got redirected again, to a log-in page.

```
# General
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/edit/data/P0000013
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

# Request Header
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:....
Host:localhost:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense.  `Authorization` is a request header, not a response header.  The browser is just ignoring it, as it should.  You should use a cookie instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. You **CANNOT** redirect with attached headers (including *basic auth*), HTTP protocol doesn't support it.
2. But you can put your basic auth key/value pair in the new url as an argument:

   HTTP/1.x 302 Found
   Location: /api?auth=asdf
3. Or save it in cookies

   HTTP/1.x 302 Found
   Location: /api
   Set-Cookie: auth=asdf

Answer (score 0):

You can specify username & password as part of [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL):

```
ctx.redirect('http://username:password@example.com');
```